# How do I combine jquery validation plugin and rails ajax object creation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-validate

The last few days I tried to find out why my jquery-validation-plugin form validation still allows the Submission even though the data is invalid.

But the jquery code is correct, I just did not considered the fact that I ajaxified the rails create action with a create.js file, which creates a new item and resets the form.

How can I prevent the AJAX code bypassing my jquery validation. Also does it even make any sense to do this? Or should I just try to display the errors via the create.js file.